# unix test when to use eq vs = vs == in test commands?

Tags: shell, test

When should I use `-eq` vs `=` vs `==`

e.g.

```
[[ $num -eq 0 ]]

[[ $num = 'zzz' ]]
```

I've observed a pattern of using `-eq` (and `-ne`, etc.) for numbers and `=` for strings.  Is there a reason for this and when should I use `==`

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Because that's the definition for those operands. From [POSIX test documentation, OPERANDS section](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html#tag_20_128_05):

> s1 =  s2
>
> True if the strings s1 and s2 are identical; otherwise, false.
>
> ...
>
> n1 -eq  n2
>
> True if the integers n1 and n2 are algebraically equal; otherwise,
>   false.

`==` is not defined by POSIX, it's an extension of `bash`, derived from `ksh`. You shouldn't use `==` when you want portability. From [bash documentation - Bash Conditional Expressions](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Conditional-Expressions.html):

> string1 == string2
>
> string1 = string2
>
> True if the strings are equal. **‘=’ should be used with the test
>   command for POSIX conformance.**

Answer (score 3):

Symbol `=` is used for string comparison while `-eq` for integer comparison. Both work with `test` and with `[...]`. If you are using `bash` then with syntax `[[...]]` you can use also `==` for string comparison. Additionally in bash `=` and `==` with `[[...]]`works for `patterns` too (as for example `[[ $x == y* ]]`.

Answer (score 3):

In a more elaborate way
Following sequences can help :

```
gnu:~$ [ sam -eq sam ]  
bash: [: sam: integer expression expected  
gnu:~$ echo "Exit status of \"[ sam -eq sam ]\" is $?."  
Exit status of "[ sam -eq sam ]" is 2.
```

---

```
gnu:~$ [ 5 -eq 5 ]  
gnu:~$ echo "Exit status of \"[ 5 -eq 5 ]\" is $?."  
Exit status of "[ 5 -eq 5 ]" is 0.
```

---

```
gnu:~$ [ 5 = 5 ]  
gnu:~$ echo "Exit status of \"[ 5 = 5 ]\" is $?."  
Exit status of "[ 5 = 5 ]" is 0.
```

---

```
gnu:~$ [ sam = sam ]  
gnu:~$ echo "Exit status of \"[ sam = sam ]\" is $?."  
Exit status of "[ sam = sam ]" is 0.
```

---

```
gnu:~$ [ 5 == 5 ]  
gnu:~$ echo "Exit status of \"[ 5 == 5 ]\" is $?."  
Exit status of "[ 5 == 5 ]" is 0.
```

---

```
gnu:~$ [ sam == sam ]  
gnu:~$ echo "Exit status of \"[ sam == sam ]\" is $?."  
Exit status of "[ sam == sam ]" is 0.
```

---

```
gnu:~$ (( 5 == 5 ))  
gnu:~$ echo "Exit status of \"(( 5 == 5 ))\" is $?."  
Exit status of "(( 5 == 5 ))" is 0.
```

---

```
gnu:~$ (( sam == sam ))  
gnu:~$ echo "Exit status of \"(( sam == sam ))\" is $?."  
Exit status of "(( sam == sam ))" is 0.
```

---

```
gnu:~$ ( sam = sam )  
The program 'sam' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:  
sudo apt-get install simon  
gnu:~$ echo "Exit status of \"( sam = sam )\" is $?."  
Exit status of "( sam = sam )" is 127.
```

---

```
gnu:~$ ( 5 = 5 )  
5: command not found  
gnu:~$ echo "Exit status of \"( 5 = 5 )\" is $?."  
Exit status of "( 5 = 5 )" is 127.
```

---

```
gnu:~$ ( sam == sam )  
The program 'sam' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:  
sudo apt-get install simon  
gnu:~$ echo "Exit status of \"( sam == sam )\" is $?."  
Exit status of "( sam == sam )" is 127.
```

---

```
gnu:~$ ( 5 == 5 )  
5: command not found  
gnu:~$ echo "Exit status of \"( 5 == 5 )\" is $?."  
Exit status of "( 5 == 5 )" is 127.
```

Answer (score 2):

From `man test`:

`-eq` , etc.

> Relay to arithmetic tests. The arguments must be entirely numeric
>   (possibly negative), or the special expression `-l STRING', which
>   evaluates to the length of STRING.

`STRING1 = STRING2`

> ```
>  True if the strings are equal.
> ```

`STRING1 == STRING2`

> ```
>  True if the strings are equal (synonym for =).
> ```

So `=` and `==` are synonyms