# what are the differences between `==` and `=` in conditional expressions?

Tags: bash

From bash manual, for conditional expressions

> ```
> string1 == string2
> string1 = string2
> ```
>
> True if the strings are equal.

1. > When used with the `[[` command, this performs pattern matching as described above (see Section 3.2.4.2 [Conditional Constructs], page
   >   10).

   - What does "pattern matching" mean here?
   - What is "pattern matching" opposed to here?
   - If not used with `[[` but with other commands, what does "this" perform?
2. > ‘=’ should be used with the `test` command for posix conformance.

   - What does POSIX say here?
   - What is the sentence opposed to?
   - Can `==` be used with `test` command? I tried and it seems yes.
   - Can `=` be used with other commands besides `test`? I tried `=` with `[[` and `[`, and it seems yes.
3. what are the differences between `==` and `=`?

   In Bash 4.3, I tried `==` and `=` with `test`, `[[`, and `[`. `==`
   and `=` look the same to me.

   Can `==` and `=` be used interchangeably in any conditional expression?

Thanks.

Comment: In short (in bash): **Yes** both `=` and `==` are the same (inside test constructs).

Comment: See also [What is the difference between \[\[ $a == z\* \]\] and \[ $a == z\* \]?](//unix.stackexchange.com/a/56674)

Comment: @Arrow (as a history note) except in bash 2.02 inside `[[...]]`

Comment: Related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/72039/whats-the-difference-between-single-and-double-equal-signs-in-shell-compari

Comment: Related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/168284/unix-test-when-to-use-eq-vs-vs-in-test-commands

Answer (score 16):

POSIX [`test`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html) (or `[ ... ]`) only knows about the one with a single equal sign:

> s1 *=*  s2
> True if the strings s1 and s2 are identical; otherwise, false.

But Bash accepts the double equal sign too, though the builtin help doesn't admit to that (the [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Conditional-Expressions.html#Bash-Conditional-Expressions) does):

```
$ help test | grep -A1 =
  STRING1 = STRING2
                 True if the strings are equal.
  STRING1 != STRING2
                 True if the strings are not equal.
```

As for other shells, it depends. Well, particularly Dash is the stubborn one here:

```
$ dash -c '[ x == x ] && echo foo'
dash: 1: [: x: unexpected operator
```

but

```
$ yash -c '[ x == x ] && echo foo'
foo
$ busybox sh -c '[ x == x ] && echo foo'
foo
$ ksh93 -c '[ x == x ] && echo foo'
foo
```

In `zsh`, `=something` is a *filename expansion* operator that expands to the path of the `something` command if found in `$PATH` unless the `equals` option is turned off (like when emulating other shells), and that also applies to `==` or `=~` when found in arguments to simple commands such as `test` or `[` so at least the leading `=` must be quoted there:

```
$ zsh -c 'echo =ls'
/usr/bin/ls

$ zsh +o equals -c 'echo =ls'
=ls

$ zsh --emulate ksh -c 'echo =ls'
=ls

$ zsh -c '[ x == x ] && echo foo'
zsh:1: = not found

$ zsh -c '[ x "==" x ] && echo foo'
foo
```

The external `test`/`[` utility from GNU coreutils on my Debian supports `==` (but the [manual](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/test.1.html) doesn't admit that), the one on OS X doesn't.

So, with `test`/`[ .. ]`, use `=` as it's more widely supported.

---

With the [`[[ ... ]]` construct](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Conditional-Constructs.html#index-_005b_005b), both `=` and `==` are equal (at least in Bash) and the right side of the operator is taken as a pattern, like  in a filename glob, unless it is quoted. (Filenames are not expanded within `[[ ... ]]`)

```
$ bash -c '[[ xxx == x* ]] && echo foo'
foo
```

But of course that construct isn't standard:

```
$ dash -c '[[ xxx == x* ]] && echo foo'
dash: 1: [[: not found
$ yash -c '[[ xx == x* ]] && echo foo'
yash: no such command ‘[[’
```

And while Busybox has it, it does't do the pattern match:

```
$ busybox sh -c '[[ xx == xx ]] && echo yes || echo no'
yes
$ busybox sh -c '[[ xx == x* ]] && echo yes || echo no'
no
```

Comment: Thanks. Do you mean that `[[ ... ]]` doesn't exist in POSIX shell,  and `==` doesn't exist in POSIX shell either?

Comment: @Tim, yes, that's correct.  Although "exist" is a slippery word.  "Aren't specified by POSIX" is more correct.  POSIX is a set of specifications, not an actual shell.

Comment: Try `help [[` and search for `==`.

Comment: `zsh`'s `[` supports `==`. It's just that `=something` is a special operator (when not emulating other shell), so needs quoted. Same problem with `=~`: `[ x '=~' . ]`, `[ x '==' x ]`.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas, I did wonder about that, and the confusing error message, thanks for the clarification!

Answer (score 6):

In bash, there are four conditions about equality:

- The simple and most basic (and only posix compatible) `=` inside `[ … ]` (or test):
  Only performs equality (byte by byte) of two strings.

  > ```
  >  STRING1 = STRING2
  >              True if the strings are equal.
  > ```
- The **extended** `==` . Which still performs (only) an equality test.

  ```
  $ [ aaaa == aaaa ] && echo yes
  yes

  $ [ aaaa == a* ] && echo yes
  $
  ```

  Be careful that the unquoted `a*` will be expanded to a filename (or several) if a matching filename exist in the pwd. In specific: an existing file named aaaa will make the code output yes. If there are no files matching, the exact comparison is afected by the failglob and nullglob shell options.
- A `=` inside a `[[` is exactly equivalent to:
- A `==` inside a `[[` does both byte-by-byte and glob matching.

  If the string or variable on the right side of the `==` is quoted, a byte comparison is made. If all the bytes are equal, the result of the `[[` is "good" (0).

  If the string, or preferable in all cases: a variable, is unquoted, the match is performed as in a filename glob.

  ```
  $ [[ aaaa == "aaaa" ]] && echo yes
  yes

  $ a='aaaa'
  $ [[ aaaa == "$a" ]] && echo yes
  yes

  $ a='a*'
  $ [[ aaaa == "$a" ]] && echo yes
  $

  $ a='a*'
  $ [[ aaaa == $a ]] && echo yes
  yes
  ```

It is interesting to note that the unquoted `aaaa` also work:

```
$ a='aaaa'
$ [[ aaaa = $a ]] && echo yes
yes
```

This happens because the string inside the variable does not have any expandable glob characters `*`, `+`, `?`, `[` and the extended (if activated) `|`, `@` and `!` . But that is usually a risky bet to use.